# Tesseract OCR - specify pattern

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to perform OCR using Tesseract (version 3.04.00).
All my images have the same pattern (digit dot digit digit, ie. a decimal with 2 digits precision). I tried using the `--user-patterns` option, but I can't have it to work.

What I did:

- create a file `patterns.txt` with `\d.\d\d` on first line
- use option `--user-patterns patterns.txt`

But I get the following error:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica read_params_file: Can't open 1 read_params_file: Can't open user-patterns read_params_file: parameter not found: \\d.\\d\\d")
```

How can I specify my pattern to Tesseract ? Is this even the right approach ?
Thanks in advance for help or advices, I don't find much doc on Tesseract.

*EDIT*: add Python code

```
img = cv2.imread("path/to/image", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="-psm 7 --user-patterns patterns.txt")
print(text)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried?The error message is relating to pytesseract, so I'm assuming you have written some code to get this error.

Comment: Edited the question. I however found a simpler approach, check my answer. I'm curious though as of why that didn't work, that would be a more general solution.

Comment: As a side note - `user-patterns` won't make tesseract return `ONLY` the patterns defined in the file. It would just slightly increase the confidence of recognized symbols if they follow the pattern, same for user-words.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. yeah I read that in the doc, but I hope it would bring improvement, because sometimes it's wrong on everything (1.13 is read LIE for example...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think Tesseract was overkill for my usecase.

I took an image of each digit from 0 to 9, and picked the minimum mean square error with the image I want to predict. Got 100% accuracy on my test dataset.